# Visual Studio Code Not Recognizing/Importing Java Projects

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm currently working at a java backend project that has multiple java subprojects configurated in it. I want to use Visual Studio Code as my editor/IDE. I've installed the following extensions:

- Debugger for Java
- Extension Pack for Java
- Maven for Java
- Project Manager for Java
- Test Runner for Java
- Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat

I don´t know why but when adding the project's folder to the workspace it only recognizes 2 of the subprojects within the complete project from a total of 25 subprojects. Any recommendation on what could it be? All the not recognized subprojects do have their own pom.xml file and practically the same structure as both of the subprojects that vscode did recognize.

[image: Subprojects recognized by VSCode]

Thank you for your help

Comment: It looks like the projects which do not display has some problems, then they can not be recognized as a java project. Have you tried to open them one by one?

Answer (score 2):

VS Code has the concept of 'workspace' which lets you add multiple folders to VS Code in the same window. `File > Add Folder to Workspace` command brings up an Open Folder dialog to select the new folder.

[image]